# Rerfreshing android camera roll in unity3d

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I made a simple app for android devices that uses mobile's camera to take a photo and save it in internal storage folder /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camerizeman/

Photos are saved correctly but the problem that i am faceing is that i can't see the photos from mobile's gallery. I can see them correctly if i use a file manager or reboot me device. i am searchig 10 days now and the problem is that i have to refresh the gallery after saving the image.

I didn't found any working solution.

my code is bellow:

```
RenderTexture renderTex;
Texture2D screenshot;
Texture2D LoadScreenshot;
int width = Screen.width; // for Taking Picture
int height = Screen.height; // for Taking Picture
string fileName;
string myScreenshotLocation;
string screenShotName = "MyImage_AR_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss") + ".png";
public void Snapshot ()
{
StartCoroutine (CaptureScreen ());
}
public IEnumerator CaptureScreen ()
{
yield return null; // Wait till the last possible moment before screen rendering to hide the UI
//GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Snapshoot").SetActive(false);
yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame (); // Wait for screen rendering to complete
if (Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.Portrait || Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown) {
mainCamera = Camera.main.GetComponent<Camera> (); // for Taking Picture
renderTex = new RenderTexture (width, height, 24);
mainCamera.targetTexture = renderTex;
RenderTexture.active = renderTex;
mainCamera.Render ();
screenshot = new Texture2D (width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
screenshot.ReadPixels (new Rect (0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
screenshot.Apply (); //false
RenderTexture.active = null;
mainCamera.targetTexture = null;
}
if (Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft || Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.LandscapeRight) {
mainCamera = Camera.main.GetComponent<Camera> (); // for Taking Picture
renderTex = new RenderTexture (height, width, 24);
mainCamera.targetTexture = renderTex;
RenderTexture.active = renderTex;
mainCamera.Render ();
screenshot = new Texture2D (height, width, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
screenshot.ReadPixels (new Rect (0, 0, height, width), 0, 0);
screenshot.Apply (); //false
RenderTexture.active = null;
mainCamera.targetTexture = null;
}
myScreenshotLocation = myFolderLocation + screenShotName;
File.WriteAllBytes (myFolderLocation + screenShotName, screenshot.EncodeToPNG ());
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`MediaScannerConnection`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html). You need the image "scanned into" the gallery.

Native Java Code goes something like:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(unityPlayerActivity, new String[]{externalImagePath}, null, null);
```

May Create plugin - [**Unity Android plugin tutorial** (1/3) Fundamentals](http://eppz.eu/blog/unity-android-plugin-tutorial-1/) -, or use [**`AndroidJavaClass.CallStatic`**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaClass.html) to invoke a `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile`.

Comment: Sure @Geri... thanks you so much.. i will appriciate your help!

Comment: can you create a private chat in here so we can talk Geri?

Comment: .. :-( i need 20 reputation to chat... any email to send you my fb acc?

Comment: Simplified the answer, use Google for details.

Answer (score 2):

The second working solution is:

```
using (AndroidJavaClass jcUnityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
        using (AndroidJavaObject joActivity = jcUnityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
        using (AndroidJavaObject joContext = joActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getApplicationContext"))
        using (AndroidJavaClass jcMediaScannerConnection = new AndroidJavaClass("android.media.MediaScannerConnection"))
        using (AndroidJavaClass jcEnvironment = new AndroidJavaClass("android.os.Environment"))
        using (AndroidJavaObject joExDir = jcEnvironment.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getExternalStorageDirectory"))
        {
            jcMediaScannerConnection.CallStatic("scanFile", joContext, new string[] { YOURFULL IMAGE PATH}, null, null);
        }
```

Comment: I was in the process of posting my answer. Never mind. +1